# model 'mealitem' has no table

Tags: database, model, odoo-10

[image]I'm creating have created more thants 10 models in odoo, I have tryed to create a model name 'mealitem', but it generated eroor:
***"model mealitem has no table"***

```
class meal_list(models.Model):
    _name="mealitem"

    name=fields.Char("The Name")
```

the strange here, is that when i use the same code and une another name like ***allitem***

```
class meal_list(models.Model):
    _name="allitem"

    name=fields.Char("The Name")
```

there is any error!! so i'm not understanding why the name **mealitem** don't work again!!

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log says that many models that you have been creating has no access rules, and its just a WARM, not a ERROR, to avoid this messages, you need add the proper access rules for every new model, creating a `ir.model.access.csv` file under `your_module_name/security/ir.model.access.csv`, and add the declaration on `__openerp__.py` file for v8 or `__manifest__.py` file for v10. Take a look others model access files like `account/security/ir.model.access.csv`.